# How to understand "against something"?

Tags: prepositions

In a code comment:

```
# The code will first check if it's running under benchmarking mode
# or evaluation mode, depending on 'eval':
# Under the evaluation mode, this script will read a saved model,
#   and compute the accuracy of the model **against** a validation dataset.
```

I cannot understand its usage even after reading the dictionary.

Comment: I think "compute" here means "compute and compare". The validation dataset is a standard result, against which the code's results are tested.

Answer (score 2):

This usage can be found in [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/against) sense 6:

> **against**: used for comparing one thing or amount with another
>
> - *This year’s profits amounted to only $35 million, against $52 million last year.*

[Collins Cobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/against)  (sense 11) gives a clearer example:

> If something is measured or valued against something else, it is
> measured or valued by comparing it with the other thing.
>
> - *Our policies have to be judged against a clear test: will it improve the standard of education?*

*Check your answers against the answer-sheet* (= *Check your answers against* those on *the answer-sheet.*) [[HMHCO](https://www.hmhco.com/blog/grades-6-8-math-activity-set-4)]

Comment: I see. against == comparing with

Comment: 'compute the accuracy of the model **against** a validation dataset' = compute the accuracy of the model by comparing results with those given by a validation dataset'.